# Script to gdisk /dev/sdX and enter expert commands: x, z, y, y - how?

Tags: partition-table, gdisk, sgdisk

I am creating my first Arch Linux install script, and I want to automate the base installation as in the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) or you can find the same instructions but easier to read here: https://www.gloriouseggroll.tv/arch-linux-efi-install-guide/

I wish to wipe the partition tables, manually I have to type this:

```
gdisk /dev/sda
x
z
y
y
```

I want the bash script to automatically do this.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Thank you! The installation instructions are here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide to be very specific, I am skipping some of the (minor) steps there.

I am usually installing Arch exactly like so: https://www.gloriouseggroll.tv/arch-linux-efi-install-guide/ (actually it is just the same as in the Archwiki, just easier to follow in my opinion).

Comment: @don_crissti I just found out about sgdisk!

What I have right now: sgdisk -Z /dev/sdX  || Equals to gdisk /dev/sda (+expert commands: x, z, y, y)

Answer (score 15):

Per the author of `gdisk`, Rod Smith, the proper tool for this kind of job is [`sgdisk`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk-walkthrough.html) — a command-line program intended for use in scripts or by experts who need quick and direct access to a specific feature.
The equivalent of `gdisk`'s interactive `x`,`z`,`y`,`y` ([wiping out GPT data)](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/wipegpt.html) is

```
sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sda
```

or

```
sgdisk -Z /dev/sda
```